# Java/Android: Handler and a for loop to show some elements of an array

Tags: android, arrays, loops, delay

i have Array buttons (10 buttons )

and i want to show these buttons with delay using Handler

**but the problem is i don't want to show all the buttons !**

i mean , i saved some buttons using **SharedPreferences** and those buttons will be INVISIBLE in the loop.

**so now here's the thing** , how can i use the **Handler.postDelayed**

to show the buttons that aren't saved as INVISIBLE ?

here's an example:

```
    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Button btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    Button btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);

// Buttons Array
        Button myBtns[] = new Button[]{btn1, btn2 , btn3 , btn4 , btn5};


   // Handler
myHandler = new Handler();

    for (int x=0; x<myBtns.length; x++)
    {
        if (!MysharedpreForSAVEDBtns.getBoolean(myBtns[x].getId()+"",false))
        {

            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {




       public void run() {

// now how can i show buttons one by one ???
                        myBtns[x].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                }, 500 * x);

            }
        }
```

**now how can i show buttons one by one ???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int x = 0; x < myBtns.length; x++){
        final int finalX = x;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 myBtns[finalX].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 500*x);
 }
```

or you can use like this

```
Handler uiThreadHandler  = new Handler();
    showDelayed(btn1, delaytime);
    showDelayed(btn2, delaytime);


 public void showDelayed(final View v, int delay){
    uiThreadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Hope this will work

Comment: it looked so easy when you did it lol , Thank you so much man! have a nice day : )

Answer (score 0):

Update visibilit of view in Ui thread as following:

```
public void run () {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    myBtns[x].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                });

                            }, 500 * x);
                        }
```